# SharePoint 2016 s4-ribbonrow & SuiteBarTop hide

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, branding

I want to hide these two elements.This works when I add display:none in developer tool but doesn't work when I add in my css file.

```
#s4-ribbonrow 
{
display:none;
}
```

Same with SuiteBarTop.The idea is to hide them on the home page to save the space.

Comment: Try changing it to `#s4-ribbonrow { display:none !important; }` instead. There could be a CSS rule with higher precedence than your CSS. Alternatively you could add JS to the page to inject the CSS rule directly onto the element.

Answer (score 2):

The following style for your reference.

```
<style>
#s4-ribbonrow{
    display:none !important;
}
#suiteBarTop{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

You can also open .master page using SharePoint designer 2013 and find the "s4-ribbonrow" and "suiteBarTop" div, then add "style='display:none'" to the div attribute.

If you use modern UI, we can add the style into [react script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to achieve it.